# Ubuntu 16.04 can not log in after new xorg.conf

Tags: 16.04, xorg, xorg.conf

I have created xorg.conf file in tty (Ctrl+alt+F1).After that I can not log in,when I put password,I am in a loop and can not log in.I do not have any problems in tty.How to solve this?

Comment: Login from Console (Ctrl + Alt + F1) and move (mv) the Xorg.conf file. `sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.bad` . Restart the X-server or Reboot.

Comment: @NickTh I have tried this,not working.It seems that I have problem with lightdm.

Comment: @MikiBelavista reinstall lightdm or reconfigure it: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` see if it helps.